# Eclipse - error while formatting javascript with html tags

Tags: javascript, eclipse, formatting, formatter

I'm using Eclipse Version: `4.2.0` and Build id: `I20120608-1400`. I have following code in JavaScript.

[image]

But when I hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>F</kbd>, it gives code in following format.

[image]

It modifies the code as above. I came to know it is due to `<br>` tag. But I want `<br>` tag there. Is it a bug or do I need to manage setting? How can I resolve this problem?

Comment: what is the behaviour with <br> replaced with <br/> ?

Comment: sorry for the late reply. The behavior with `<br/>` is same as `<br>`. same problem.

Comment: maybe try  separating <br> tag from the folllowing string? like: "<br>" + "Upload error...

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is a bug. You can find lots of bug reports from [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382474) and also [here](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388340). I guess the [first link's attachment](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=218897) solves the problem. The message says:

> Created attachment 218897 [details] Fix for JsTranslator.java
>
> In the following method:
>   org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core.javascript.JsTranslator.translateJSNode(IStructuredDocumentRegion)
>
> 'generatedContent' is not correctly cleared in the loop.
>
> I have attached a patch.

Comment: Thank you reply. But I couldn't find `JsTranslator.java`. How to apply the patch? I'm really lost.

Comment: Do you have Kepler version?

Comment: Download this version: http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/technology/epp/downloads/release/kepler/R/eclipse-jee-kepler-R-win32-x86_64.zip. The file is in eclipse>>plugins>>org.eclipse.wst.jsdt.web.core_1.0.600.v201301301822. Open this file with winrar and navigate to org>>eclipse>>wst>>jsdt>>web>>core>>javascript. The file is there. Just open it apply the solution: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/attachment.cgi?id=218897&action=diff